# using bindParam with PDO

Tags: php, pdo

I've been scratching my head over this code for a couple of hours....
Doesn't make sense to me why it doesn't work

```
$isCorrect =($question->correct_answer == $body->answer) ? 1:0;
// the values are all there.......
// echo $body->question . "\n"; //335
// echo $body->user . "\n";     //51324123
// echo $question->day . "\n"; //0
// echo $isCorrect . "\n";     //0

//but still the below part fails.
$db = getConnection();
$sql = "INSERT INTO `answers` (`id`, `question_id`, `user`, `day`, `is_correct`) VALUES (NULL, ':question', ':user', ':day', :is_correct)";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);  
$stmt->bindParam(":question_id", $body->question);
$stmt->bindParam(":user", $body->user);
$stmt->bindParam(":day", $question->day, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam(":is_correct", $isCorrect, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
```

gives this error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens
```

I'm counting 4 tokens... what am I missing? Obviously I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: there's an invalid number of parameters because you put your named parameter in single quotes, which is not the way to do it. named parameters `:question` must not go into single quotes, like `?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change :

```
$stmt->bindParam(":question_id", $body->question);
```

to:

```
$stmt->bindParam(":question", $body->question);
```

You have use in query `:question` but binding with wrong key(`:question_id`).

Comment: @springbo  do not forgot to accept it :) if it helps

Comment: Thank you so much both you! Amazing how I had completely stared myself blind on it.
Will accept this answer as soon as I can.
Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Try it like this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `answers` (`id`, `question_id`, `user`, `day`, `is_correct`) 
        VALUES 
        --The :variable shouldn't be surrounded by ''--
        (NULL, :question, :user, :day, :is_correct)";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
//The values used in $sql should be the same here, so not :question_id but :question
$stmt->bindParam(":question", $body->question);
$stmt->bindParam(":user", $body->user);
$stmt->bindParam(":day", $question->day, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam(":is_correct", $isCorrect, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

Answer (score 1):

just don't use bindParam with PDO
as well as named parameters. it will save you a ton of headaches

```
$db = getConnection();
$sql = "INSERT INTO `answers` VALUES (NULL, ?,?,?,?)";
$data = [$body->question,$body->user,$question->day,$isCorrect];
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql)->execute($data);
```

Comment: I am asking just want to learn. Why not should we use bindParam? Is there a vulnerability?

Comment: How does PDO understand to use `$data` array? Shouldn't you pass `$data` to `execute()`

Answer (score 0):

```
$stmt->bindParam(":question_id", $body->question);
```

should be

```
$stmt->bindParam(":question", $body->question);
```

This is just a little typo.